# Why my vmware server was shutdown suddenly?

Tags: vmware

Is there anyway to investigate why my vmware server virtual machines were all suddenly shutdown?

Any logs i can check on?

Comment: this might be a question for ServerFault rather than StackOverflow

Comment: Let's migrate it to SuperUser instead!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, but it turned out I misconfigured the server. Log onto VMware Infrastructure Web Access and under "Edit Virtual Machine Startup/Shutdown" that the machines are set to either suspend or shut down when the host service is stopping. Otherwise VMware will turn them off.